# What can I use to represent data?

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid, slider, progress-bar

I'm doing a project at work where I'm taking the value of 8 sliders, running the values through a formula, then displaying that value on the screen. I would like to accompany with a type of vertical graph/bar that will span a grid. I tried using progress bars, which I ran into issues with both expanding the progress bar to the height of the grid, and displaying the value once the value went backwards. I had the same layout issues with the slider, once rotated -90 degrees the slider won't expand the height of the grid. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could try or and objects that I haven't thought of?

[image: This is the best I can do for a picture.]

Comment: You can provide some UI rendering or screenshot so that we can help you

Comment: I would suggest drawing a custom graph style representation using SkiaSharp.

Comment: SkiaSharp was unable to bind to a grid

Answer (score 0):

I've been happy using Syncfusion to chart data in Xamarin.Forms. It sets up fast and comes with lots of friendly defaults so you can see right away whether it's working. [Link to Syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/introduction/overview). If you want to see it used for real [I'm using it in my app over here](https://github.com/KRA2008/cringebot).

It sounds like from your question and the comments that while you're intent on charting data you're also very set on using a Grid to do something. From many experiences I've had in the past I would warn you to be careful about blaming the graphing/charting/drawing library for things going haywire when the problem could very well be that you are using the wrong layout or using it in the wrong way.